# Get (row number, col number) using apply(matrix,1:2,f)

Tags: r, apply

What would be the best way with apply(matrix,1:2,f) to get for every position of the matrix the couple (row number, col number)?

```
f <- function(x){
  i=row(x)
  j=col(x)
  return(i,j)
}
apply(matrix,1:2,f)
```

ERROR :

> Error in row(x) : a matrix-like object is required as argument to
> 'row'

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using dataframes and without `apply()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
f <- function(x){
  i=as.data.frame(row(x))
  j=as.data.frame(col(x))
  #Values
  i1 <- pivot_longer(i,everything())
  j1 <- pivot_longer(j,everything()) %>% rename(value2=value)
  #Merge
  k <- i1 %>% left_join(j1) %>% mutate(Pos=paste0('(',value,',',value2,')')) %>%
    select(Pos) %>% filter(!duplicated(Pos))
  return(k$Pos)
}
#Apply
A <- matrix(2,2,2)
f(A)
```

Output:

```
[1] "(1,1)" "(1,2)" "(2,1)" "(2,2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the indices using `seq` and `rep`.

```
matidx <- function(m) {
  i <- nrow(m); j <- ncol(m)
  cbind(row = rep(seq_len(i), each = j), col = rep(seq_len(j), i))
}
```

The output should look like this

```
> head(matidx(mtcars), 20)
      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   1   2
 [3,]   1   3
 [4,]   1   4
 [5,]   1   5
 [6,]   1   6
 [7,]   1   7
 [8,]   1   8
 [9,]   1   9
[10,]   1  10
[11,]   1  11
[12,]   2   1
[13,]   2   2
[14,]   2   3
[15,]   2   4
[16,]   2   5
[17,]   2   6
[18,]   2   7
[19,]   2   8
[20,]   2   9
```